# why not executed subprocess ffmpeg in online windows virtual server django?

Tags: django, windows, ffmpeg, server, virtual

this is my code:

```
subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i ' + media_in + ''' -ss 00:00:01 -frames:v 1 -vf "scale=w='min(150\, iw*3/2):h=-1'" ''' + image_out, shell=True)
```

**image_out** is result of a video.

My code is executed correctly on localhost and output.

Although I installed ffmpeg on a virtual server in the c:/ drive and made the environment settings

**But in Deploy mode, it does not run on Windows Virtual Server and does not output?**

> Does not run on the my web site
>
> Blockquote

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: nothing error, don't have any Output sorry

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question
Restarting Windows Server solved the problem.